# Using ICA over MIT BIH NST dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

In [this dataset](https://physionet.org/content/nstdb/1.0.0/), I wanted to use signals with same unit and different SNR as input signals  in ICA, i.e.

```
ica_input = np.array([ record_118e_6(MLII),
record_118e00(MLII),
record_118e06(MLII),
record_118e12(MLII),
record_118e18(MLII)
])
```

Is this a correct input to ICA?
Can I here consider the signal with different SNR linear mix of noises and true signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://physionet.org/physiotools/wag/nst-1.htm) article (which states how the dataset is generated by nst), The above input channels are linear mix of noise and clean signal and from plotting one can see that this data is clearly non gaussian hence ICA can be used in this case. Please correct me if I am wrong.